# On what basis python orders dict?

Tags: python

I have simple list of data which looks like:

```
_MOBILE_CATEGORIES = {
    100152307: 424,
    100152547: 55,
    100152385: 66,
    100152395: 13,
    100152405: 130,
    100152365: 50,
    100152290: 218,
    100152446: 26
}
```

When I print it I get:

> {100152385: 66, 100152290: 218, 100152307: 424, 100152405: 130,
>   100152547: 55, 100152395: 13, 100152365: 50, 100152446: 26}

As you cant see first goes `100152385: 66` which in list is third.

```
_MOBILE_CATEGORIES = {
    '100152307': 424,
    '100152547': 55,
    '100152385': 66,
    '100152395': 13,
    '100152405': 130,
    '100152365': 50,
    '100152290': 218,
    '100152446': 26
}
```

If I define keys as string I get other order like this:

> {'100152290': 218, '100152307': 424, '100152385': 66, '100152446': 26,
>   '100152405': 130, '100152395': 13, '100152365': 50, '100152547': 55}

So I need to define dict so that it would be in the order I need?

Answer (score 2):

Python dicts are unordered by their own nature. To get the feature you want use an [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).